# jQuery/CSS Offset + mousemove question

Tags: jquery, css, offset, mousemove

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H45uY/6/
What I'm trying to do here is make the top-left corner of the `<div>` follow the mouse. The code works fine without the paragraph (see demo above), but when you add a paragraph, the `<div>` is pushed up and the mouse is halfway down the side of the box. Why does the paragraph do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove `- offset.top` and `- offset.left` it works in every position

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Detzw/)

Answer (score 2):

add **top:0** and **left:0** to the div style

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to subtract the offset.

```
$div.css({
    top:event.pageY,
    left:event.pageX
})
```

This will put the box at the mouse position.